# how to specify fluent api for newly created table in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to display top 5 popular product on my home page.

i am trying to study the nopcommerce project.

so i have decided to make 1 table in which i will maintain this:

**ProductMostViewed**:

**Id      ProductId   ProductViewcount**

1 more thing i am not getting is can i directly create this table in sql server management studio??

here do i need to add category field or productid will do.

like for eg.**Computer**==>**Desktop**==>**HP Pavilion Elite M9150F Desktop PC**

so when any user will open any particular product detail page then i will increment in ProductViewcount.

but one thing i am not getting is where do i create this class file and where do i specify fluent api and is this appropriate solution for doing this task???

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/14123/step-by-step-tutorial-for-adding-a-new-table-to-nopcommerce-23.aspx#92781) link can help you to fix out your issue.